# CodeIgniter - Update User's Account details with a form input

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

Im new to codeigniter and unsure of my issue

I want the current logged in user to be able to be able to edit their account details (username, email) and update it to the database.. i currently have the details showing in the form but when i press the update button the page just reloads and nothing happens

My Controller - Dashboard

```
     public function update()
        {
         $updated_data = array(
            'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
            'email' => $this->input->post('email'));

    $this->load->model('Account_model');
            $this->Account_model->updateM($updated_data, $this->input->post('id'));
            redirect('Dashboard/account');
        }
```

My Model - Account_model

```
public function updateM($updated_data, $user_id)
{
$this->db->where('id', $user_id);
$this->db->update('users',$updated_data);
}
```

My view - account

```
<?php
      foreach ($results as $result):
      ?>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" value="<?php echo $result->username;?>" />
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $result->email;?>" />


  <?php
    $bttn = '<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Update Details"/>';
    echo anchor("main/update/$result->id", $bttn);?>
  </div>
</form>
<?php endforeach; ?>
  <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Any help will be massively appreciated as i am a newbie

Comment: You need to get the user's id from the session, not from post so ``$this->input->post('id')`` should be ``$this->session->userdata('user_id')`` or whatever you name you gave to the user id in your session

Comment: you are absolutely right,  it is working now, thankyou so much, if you can leave as an answer i will mark as correct